# How do I generate random numbers in Toit?

Tags: toit

I'm writing code in Toit. How do I generate pseudo random numbers from a program written in Toit?

I am interested in generating integers in a specific range and floats in the half-open interval from 0 (included) to 1 (not included).

Comment: I see you have built a new programming language and hardware. Nice. But where is the SDK?

Comment: The Toit SDK and the associated infrastructure is currently only available to a select group of early adaptors who are building on our stack and through that helping us shape our platform technology. We will be opening up more over time, but I understand that seeing our code snippets with no way to run them is a bit of a teaser at this point in time.

Comment: @KasperLund please do read our [FAQ for supporting your community on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community), especially on the subject of seeding questions. If this is for an SDK with a restricted audience then seeding posts on Stack Overflow is rather premature. Please hold of and let a community build organically, instead.

Comment: Thanks, @MartijnPieters! You are right that we have been trying to support our growing community on Stack Overflow through seeding to get the ball rolling a bit. I appreciate your feedback and we will try to strike a better balance going forward to allow for the community to build itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to generate a pseudo random integer in Toit is to use the `random` method from the core library:

```
main:
  n := random
  log "random integer is $n"
```

The `random` method allows you to specify a constraint on the range, so you can get 20 random numbers between 0 and 10 (exclusive) logged like this:

```
main:
  20.repeat:
    log "random integer is $(random 10)"
```

If you want to get a pseudo random floating point number in the range from 0 to 1 (exclusive), you can convert the integer to a float through division:

```
main:
  x := (random 10_000).to_float / 10_000
  log "random float is $x"
```

Comment: How do I use more of the bits of the random generator? In C++ I could have e.g. a 32 bit state and divide by std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(). And how many bits of state does the random generator have or what is its period?

Comment: The internal state is 128 bits wide, but right now we only surface the lowest 28 bits of them through a call to random without any arguments. That is, you could call `random.to_float / ((1 << 28) - 1)` and use more bits through that. You're welcome to file a [feature request](https://github.com/toitware/public/issues) and provide details on what you'd like to see.